# Pentaho Kettle - Unable to connect to virtual Oracle Database

Tags: oracle, pentaho

I'm attempting to connect to a virtualized Oracle database but I am receiving the following error:

Error connecting to database: (using class oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver)
Listener refused the connection with the following error:

> ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in
>   connect descriptor The Connection descriptor used by the client was:
>   foohost:1521:foodba

Since SIDs are not usable with virtualized databases I need to provide a fully qualified URL (from what I have heard), however I'm not certain how to configure Pentaho to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2):

So the trick was to go into the Options tab in the Edit Connection dialogue and create a database parameter to define the connection string.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about pentaho or kettle, but you could try using EZCONNECT syntax for the connection descriptor: `//host:1521/sid`

Comment: Pentaho accepts the host, pid and server name as 3 separate strings and concatenates them to form the connection string. I'm looking for a way to configure Pentaho to use the alternate syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the insight and apologies for the unsatisfactory answer. you may need to change the relevant `sqlnet.ora` file on your client to allow you to do this, e.g.: `NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH=(ezconnect, tnsnames)`